# AWS Capstone project gives 502 error on dns query

Tags: amazon-web-services, capstone

I work on Cloud architecting module of AWS, In capstone project I successfully setup loadbalancer and scaling group while querying in using DNS it shows 502 error on query section while it works efficiently for cloud9 instance.

[Entering the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38uAm.png)

[After sometime it shows 502 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D91FG.png)

Comment: I can see for query2.php it errors out, but for query.php it works, is your backend configured for query2.php, and have your checked your CloudWatch Metrics?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.